# Does an IP address always have a corresponding domain name/URL?

Tags: networking

Apologizes if this is readily available somewhere but I'm not able to find it on google easily.

I'm wondering if an IP address will always have a corresponding domain name/URL. We are looking to remove acceptance of IP addresses and require our clients to pass a domain name instead but wanted to ensure that this is possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and answers are too short to fit in SO's format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **No.**

An IP with a corresponding domain name/URL is strictly for readability purposes. You can map a particular IP to a domain name using a DNS server but it is entirely optional.

[More info](http://wiki.bravenet.com/How_the_domain_name_system_works#IP_Addresses)